# Размер кода компиляторов

Tags: компилятор, компиляция

Добрый день. Извиняюсь за ранее за вопрос из домашнего задания, просто не понимаю вообще, как к нему подойти, вопрос теоретически:

Изучил немного язык Swift, в теоретической части задается вопрос о "длине" его компилятора, измеряемым в количестве строк, символов или общем размере.

Может кто мне обяснить где эту инфрмацию откопать, в каких недрах ? 
Есть ссылка на [source](https://github.com/apple/swift), но я понятия не имею, что из этой кучи файлов есть компилятор и темболее как его измерить ? 
Дурацкий вопрос, но все же, помогите пожалуйста.

Также нужно найти компилятор другого языка, на каком языке он был написал и также его размер, для сравнения.

Comment: Ну, будет разумным предположить, что из этой кучи файлов _всё_ компилятор.

Comment: если воспользоваться скриптом из [вопроса про подсчет строк](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository), то можно получить цифру: 1381170

Comment: @VladD, ну там вообще еще тесты, benchmark, доки и куча чего еще :)

Comment: Grundy, я немного запутался со скриптом, нужно повозиться со своим powershell-ом, чтобы заработал. 
Можешь подсказать на счет Perl 5 вот по этой ссылке например: 
https://github.com/Perl/perl5
Вопрос тот же, сколько строк, буду благодарен.

Comment: @Grundy: Ну да. Но _документация является частью компилятора_. И тесты тоже! Проект без тестов — инкубатор багов.

Comment: @Avenger, `1361403`, я использовал код из [этого ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32154303/2881286). Но результаты могут быть не совсем корректны

Answer (score 1):

> но я понятия не имею, что из этой кучи файлов есть компилятор и тем более как его измерить

Да, искать такую информацию по исходникам - дело не простое. Но, @Avenger, этот вопрос сложный на первый взгляд. Но как говорят "в правильно заданном вопросе - содержится 50% ответа". Смотрим вопрос "размер кода компилятора". Обращаем внимание на то, что не указано кода **какого именно** языка программирования, не указано, что обязательно нужно искать в исходниках! Поэтому смело используем эту лазейку.

**И тогда становится все просто**

- ищем статически-слинкованные модули рассматриваемых компиляторов
- дизассемблируем их, получаем код на ассемблере

Количество строк и размер листинга - получены. Для получения количества символов используем утилиту [nm](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) (из пакета [binutils](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils)) опять же - над исполняемыми файлами выбранных компиляторов. Тут уж придется самостоятельно покурить мануал по нужным ключам, которые позволят сформировать нужные статы по символам.

Comment: Отлично. 
Где найти эти модули, есть готовые источники на примере ? 
В остальном понятно. Но да, одно требование есть касательно Свифта, а на счет второго языка, можно взять любой, лишь бы добыть информацию.

Comment: Я бы поступил так: заинсталлил в виртуальной машине какой-нибудь "хозяйский" дистрибутив Linux, например, Manjaro (https://manjaro.ru), потом полазил по сайтам интересующих компиляторов. Если уже есть бинарные сборки, скачал бы их, если нет - собрал бы из исходников. Ну конечно имеет смысл заранее  посмотреть и в собственных репозитариях линуха - и там возможно есть интересующее.

Comment: В принципе, на торрентах есть и предустановленные ВМ для гостевой Mac OS X. Если она конечно "роднее" линухов.